# How to load a session by its id in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, memcached

Im having a hard time trying to figure out how to load a session by its id.
I don't want the current_user session, I need to load another one (mostly because flash doesnt share sessions with the browser). So I'm passing the session_id forward with the parameters, how do I get the session in the other side?
Authlogic is redirecting me to login page aways...

I'm usign mem_cached_store to store the sessions. But I'm looking for something 'find_by_id', any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the session id, you can pull the session out of memcached with the session id prefixed with "session:".

```
session_key = "session:#{session_id}"
mcache = MemCache.new('localhost')
user_session = mcache.get(session_key)
```